# Аналог DataSnap в .NET(С#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть ли аналог DataSnap в С#?
В своем приложении использую Linq to SQL. Есть ли в нем возможность контроля параллельного доступа?

Answer (score 1):

если вам нужен асинхронный доступ к БД, то можете почитать [LINQ to SQL: Asynchronously Executing Queries](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/12/06/10008.aspx),
а Parellel LINQ это LINQ to object

Answer (score -1):

Я не знаю, что такое DataSnap, поэтому не смогу ответить по поводу аналога. Касательно параллельного доступа, есть [Parellel LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460688.aspx).